# rotate the currently playing animation with mouse movement

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I tried with a for loop, so every animation that is executed according to the state in the Animations class is stored in an instance variable belonging to the Player class, i.e. `self.images` is matched with the instance variable `self.original_image` and then rotates according to the specified angle, but this doesn't work, pixel in the picture becomes messy and rotates aimlessly and soon pygame raises an error : `pygame.error: Out of memory`. I've tried other ways, such as replacing the original animation list with a rotated image list, but the result is the same.

```
import os
import sys
import math

import pygame


clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

FPS = 60


class Animations:
    def __init__(self):
        self.frame = 0
        self.animations_loop = []
        self.animations_db = {}

    @staticmethod
    def search_png(path):
        return [img for img in os.listdir(path) if img.endswith(".png")]

    @staticmethod
    def load_image(path):
        img = pygame.image.load(path)
        trans = pygame.transform.scale(img, (80, 80))

        return trans

    def load_images(self, path):
        images = []
        
        images_dir = self.search_png(path)
        for image in images_dir:
            load = self.load_image(f"{path}/{image}")

            images.append(load)

        return images

    def load_animations(self, name, images, frame_durations, loop=True):
        images = self.load_images(images)

        if loop:
            self.animations_loop.append(name)

        data = []
        for image in range(len(images)):
            for _ in range(frame_durations):
                data.append(images[image])

        self.animations_db[name] = data

    def get_animations(self):
        return self.animations_db[self.state]

    def set_state(self, new_state):
        self.state = new_state

    def frame_control(self):
        if self.frame >= len(self.animations_db[self.state]):
            self.frame = 0 if self.state in self.animations_loop else len(self.animations_db[self.state])

    def frame_increase(self):
        self.frame += 1

    def play(self, screen, position):
        self.frame_increase()
        self.frame_control()
        screen.blit(self.animations_db[self.state][self.frame-1], position)


class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        path = "..\..\sprites\sprite Rotoscoped zombie and soldier"
        self.anim = Animations()
        self.anim.load_animations("idle", f"{path}\soldier-idle", 4)
        self.anim.load_animations("walk", f"{path}\soldier-walk", 4)
        self.anim.set_state("idle")
        self.images = self.anim.get_animations()
        self.original_image = self.images
        self.position = pygame.math.Vector2((200, 200))
        self.rect = self.images[0].get_rect(center=self.position)

    def move(self, up=False, down=False, right=False, left=False):
        move = [0, 0]
        
        if up:
            move[1] = -2
        elif down:
            move[1] = 2
        elif right:
            move[0] = 2
        elif left:
            move[0] = -2

        self.rect.x += move[0]
        self.rect.y += move[1]

        if move[0] != 0 or move[1] != 0:
            self.anim.set_state("walk")

    def rotate(self, mx, my):
        for image in range(len(self.images)):
            rel_x, rel_y = self.position[0] - mx, self.position[1] - my
            angle = (180 / math.pi) * -math.atan2(rel_x, rel_y)
            self.images[image] = pygame.transform.rotate(self.original_image[image], angle)
            self.rect = self.images[0].get_rect(center=self.position)

    def draw(self, screen):
        self.anim.play(screen, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))


# init
soldier = Player()


while True:
    clock.tick(FPS)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            soldier.anim.set_state("idle")

    mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    soldier.rotate(mx, my)

    key_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if key_pressed[pygame.K_w]:
        soldier.move(up=True)
    elif key_pressed[pygame.K_s]:
        soldier.move(down=True)
    elif key_pressed[pygame.K_d]:
        soldier.move(right=True)
    elif key_pressed[pygame.K_a]:
        soldier.move(left=True)

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    soldier.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually only have 1 image list because `self.original_image = self.images` doesn't create a new list. `self.images` and `self.original_image` are references to the same list. What you want are 2 lists with the same objects. Create a [Shallow copy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html):

<s>`self.original_image = self.images`</s>

```py
self.original_image = self.images[:]
```

---

In addition, you can simplify the `rotate` method. If you rotate the images, the `self.images` list canbe  generated from the `self.original_image` list:

```py
def rotate(self, mx, my):
    
    rel_x, rel_y = self.position[0] - mx, self.position[1] - my
    angle = (180 / math.pi) * -math.atan2(rel_x, rel_y)

    for i, img in enumerate(self.original_image):
        self.images[i] = pygame.transform.rotate(img, angle)
            
    self.rect = self.images[0].get_rect(center=self.position)
```